# Using "Web Application Toolkit for Mobile Web Applications" for iPhone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mobile, mobile-website, toolkit

I am using the [Web Application Toolkit for Mobile Web Applications](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile) to develop a simple website (which allows to update the users) for Windows 7 Mobile and iPhone using asp.net MVC.

I am using the [ibbdemo](http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/downloads/list) as simulator to test for iPhone.

I have been facing few issues with this.

1. Javascript/Jquery is not working (I have tried to set the textbox value in document.ready in a plain page with just a textbox)
2. Form Collection of radio button returns all the values in comma separated, not only the selected one.

**Edit:**

I am trying to do the following after the admin logs in to website:

1. Show links like Active Users and Inactive Users(Main/Index).
2. Once the Admin clicks the Active Users link, then the list of active users will be shown (User/Active)
3. On Clicking the Name of the user, the page to update the User details like Name, Sex, Email,... will be shown (User/Detail)

The javascript works till the 1st step, from 2nd step, it doesn't do anything. I have tried adding a dummy textbox in (Main/Index) page and set the value in document.ready, it worked. But when i do the same in (User/Active) or (User/Detail), the javascript/jquery doesn't seem to work. To Test, I have copied the first page content to all of them, but still it works in first page but not in rest. I am puzzled with this issue.

Here is the html that looks in (Main/Index):

```
     <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Mobile/iPhone/Site.Master"
        Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1 id="pageTitle">
            </h1>
            <a id="backButton" class="button" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <form id="dashboardForm" action="Main/Index" method="get" title="Dashboard" class="panel"
        selected="true">
        <fieldset>
 <div class="row">
            <label>
                Dummy:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("dummyText") %>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label>
                    Users: <a href="/User/Detail?IsNew=true">Add</a></label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="/User/Active">Active Users</a> <a href="/User/Inactive">Inactive Users</a>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#dummyText").val('test');
        });
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

Is there any work around or did anyone face the same problem and found a solution for this?

Or is there any another toolikit for developing mobile apps using asp.net MVC, please suggest

Answer (score 1):

There is a mode in Safari(the browser from Apple), that lets you emulate Mobile Safari, the browser of the iPhone.

In the menus, find `Develop` -> `User Agent` and choose the browser you want to emulate.

Comment: Same issue in the Safari (Develop), still the javascript and radio button form issues. I have added $("#FirstName").val("Test"); or document.getElementById('FirstName').value ="Test"; in document ready, but i see no value in that textbox

Comment: Did you try to debug your code while in Safari? In the menu `Develop`->`Show Web Inspector`

Comment: Yes i did. But Its not showing any error. I have updated my question in detail after some analyzing more. Any obvious in that?

Comment: Insure you have Web inspector open and enabled, add a `debugger;` statment before `$("#dummyText").val('test');`. You should hit the debugger, and then inspect what returns `$("#dummyText")`, inspect the DOM to see what was generated, etc... Good luck.

Comment: @Mic, The debugger is not working on the second page,. When inspecting the html after clicking the active users link from first page, in the "Elements section of web inspector" its showing the first page's html and then the html of the second page with some dynamic id like "__1__" for the selected div and "__2__" for script section and keeps on adding for each click of active users link like "__3__", "__4__",...

Comment: After adding an id to the selected div and script tag, the dynamic id generation has stopped, but still the break point is not coming for the debugger in the second page. And also in script tab, the dropdown which lists all the script files and the current page, is not showing the second page.

Comment: Add a `console.log('something')` at the beginning of your JS code. Insure you see it in the console. Then add other `console.log` in the functions you think are called in the order, until your last function. And check regularly if they comme up in the console. At some point you should see a `console.log` not appearing and discover what's wrong

Comment: I have added console.log('1') in first page, it shows fine in console. When i click the Active Customers link, nothing happens, except rendering the html. I am using the following code to render the view: [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Active(long? Id)
        { List<Users> _users = null;  //Get active Users                   return View("Active", _users);}

Comment: If you set a console.log, and it does not appear, it means probably you are not running the code you think(another function, another file, another system, etc...)

Comment: i can see the value '1' that was set in the First Page in the console, but not the value set in Second page. And also whatever html changes i make in the second page, its appearing in the browser(This confirms that i am running the page i required), but no luck with the script and console.log

Comment: Did you try `top.console` if you are running different windows? If I had a so long lasting problem, I would just implement the solution differently and avoid making circle.